# Trying to convert UPDATE into MERGE

Tags: sql, oracle, merge, sql-update

My question is simple. I am trying to convert an UPDATE statement into MERGE statement for better performance, as the update count maybe between 10K - 1M. Here is my UPDATE code:

```
UPDATE table_1 t1
   SET t1.col_1 =
          (SELECT t2.name
             FROM table_2 t2
            WHERE t2.fn = t1.col_1),
       t1.Col_3 =
          (SELECT t2.name
             FROM table_2 t2
            WHERE t2.fn = t1.Col_3),
       t1.Col_5 =
          (SELECT t2.name
             FROM table_2 t2
            WHERE t2.fn = t1.Col_5);
```

I tried changing into MERGE:

```
MERGE INTO Table_1
     USING (SELECT NAME FROM table_2) A
        ON (1 = 1)
WHEN MATCHED
THEN
   UPDATE SET Table_1.col_1 = A.NAME,
              Table_1.col_3 = A.NAME,
              Table_1.col_5 = A.NAME;
```

The above code throws error, please help me sort the problem out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add the error message plaese.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle? SQL Server?

Comment: @Jens Error: Cannot get stable count to update

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I am uding Oracle 10G

Answer (score 1):

use

```
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (table_1.col1)
    VALUES (a.name);
```

Comment: A missing `when not matched` would not cause the "cannot get stable set of records" error (it would cause a syntax error at parse time)